# Wrong automatic language detection with Microsoft Translator

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

1. I'm using this api to translate text: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate
2. When user key in the keyword "tidak", it gets English as detected language, which is wrong, because there is no such word in English. It is a Malay word which means "No".
3. Is there a channel I report this to Microsoft so that they can fix the translation for this word? It is an important word in Malay for our chatbot.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. We (Microsoft Translator) will investigate what should happen here.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am experiencing the same issue. It seems that very short words default to English...

Comment: I think they have fixed the word "tidak" after I submit to https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator-api

You can try submitting the problematic words to them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get support or post your feedback [here](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator-api) .

Comment: Thanks. Submitted. Hope Microsoft can solve it soon.